# How to run batch file in coverity

Tags: coverity-prevent, coverity

I am new to coverity and i am using .bat file for building. Is there any way to build .bat file through coverity buil(cov-build) command in command line.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you building actually?  Is your bat file calling make or ant?

Comment: my bat file is calling make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,

Alter your bat file such that it wraps cov-build around make

build.bat

```
cov-build make {YOUR_OPTIONS}
```